# Django export the csv of Multiple Objects

Tags: django

I am wrong on the where？i would like to export the details of the objects

this line is < for r in x[0]['user']:> but i don't know why?

Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 0

```
def export_excel(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel; charset="Shift_JIS"')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    titles = ["No","name","date","start_time","off_time"]
    writer.writerow(titles)
    obj_all = attendance.objects.filter(id = 1).values('user', 'contact_date', 'contact_time').order_by("-contact_time")
    lea = leavework.objects.filter(id = 1).values('contact_time').order_by('-contact_time')
    row = []
    for x in obj_all:
        for r in x[0]['user']:
            row.append(r)
        writer.writerow(row)

    return response
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more information. Which line gives the key error?

Comment: this line is < for r in x[0]['user']:> but i don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do to figure this out:

```
for x in obj_all:
    try:
        for r in x[0]['user']:
            row.append(r)
        writer.writerow(row)
    except KeyError as e:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Then, I'd reload the view in the development server (you're using `manage.py runserver` right?), and that'd give me a PDB prompt.

From that, I'd take a look at `x`, since I think the problem (based on your `KeyError` referring to the key `0` being missing). You can look at variables using `dir(x)` to see what attributes `x` has, and just `p x` to print out ``x`.

If you're new to PDB, [Steve Ferb's guide to PDB](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/) should help get you started.

Comment: My development server is CentOS Apache,  I just have the this error Django Version:1.6.2
Exception Type: BdbQuit
Exception Location: /usr/lib64/python2.6/bdb.py in dispatch_line, line 65
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version:2.6.6

Comment: That's because you quit BDB. Did you manage to learn anything about ``x``?